# Getting error as "setCustomValidity is not a function"

Tags: javascript

I have added validation in my JS which isgiving error as

> Uncaught TypeError: contactdate.setCustomValidity is not a function.

My JS code is as follows:

```js
function contactDateValidation() {
  var contactdate = new Date($('#date1').val()); // or Date.parse(...)

  // var contactdate = $("#date1").val();  
  var dateNow = new Date(); // or Date.now()
  if (contactdate < dateNow) {
    contactdate.setCustomValidity('Date cannot be less than todays date');
  } else {
    $("#date1").setCustomValidity("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of  `setCustomValidity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> contactdate.setCustomValidity('Date cannot be less than todays date');
> ```

The variable `contactdate` is a Date object, which doesn't have a function called `setCustomValidity`. You probably intend to use that on `$("#date1")`.

You need to call it on an element, so it should be something like:

```
$("#date1")[0].setCustomValidity("");
```

You can read more about constraint validations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

```js
$("#date1")[0].setCustomValidity("Test")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="date1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Made a mistake by using date obj.